# Why do I need Transaction logs at all

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

We use Microsoft SQL Server as a repository of images and data about those images. We record in real time and never care about recovery. If the database slows down and can't handle the number of images, we report this event to the user.

So why do I need to use transactions? Even if the user deletes the images, we do not care about attempting any type of recovery.

All we care about is performance to store the image data. It seem that the transaction process and logs are as big as a master file.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have any persistence requirements at all? If all images were to be somehow lost following a hardware fault would that be a problem or is all of it disposable?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the core of the question ignores how RDBMS systems work.

Comment: The phrase "we never care about recovery" does not compute.

Comment: @MikeFal Postgres has no logged tables AFAIK.

Comment: and just because ***you*** don't care about it doesn't mean that the majority of use cases don't either. why not just use a file system and a binary .dat file instead of a database server?

Comment: Wait wait I just re-read this. So you want to store data just not retain any of it? Why store it in the first place?

Comment: also, is the question behind the question, "the fact that my transaction logs are not being maintained and are eating up my drive space is inconvenient and annoying, please suggest a way to help me manage my logs."?

Comment: @MartinSmith That sounds like an exception rather than a standardized RDBMS implementation.  Are these tables ACID compliant?

Comment: Why are you using a database at all?

Comment: Can you tell us more about what this system is doing with the images? It's possible that using SQL Server may not be the best solution for your needs.

Comment: @MikeFal No. They are lost on crash or unclean shutdown. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it requires much more detail about your use case including disaster recovery requirements.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server is a [A.C.I.D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) compliant relational database platform, and transaction logs are a critical aspect of this component.  Without a transaction log, SQL Server could not ensure any of those attributes.  SQL Server wasn't designed to be a 'file store', it was designed to be a data store.  Essentially you guys might be using the wrong tool for the job.

If your transaction logs are as big as your actual data files you might not be truncating the data within the log files, or there's a lot of optimization the app layer needs in finishing old transactions.  Are you in the SIMPLE recovery mode?

Yes, I have been in shops that use SQL Server to store binary data or in this case, .zip files, it works but there's issues as well.  Typically they go with the VARCHAR(MAX) data type, which could let you fill up the entire hard drive with 1 row of data, and it happened before.

If you have to, look at FILESTREAM or the 2014 in memory tables, although I don't think in memory tables work with BLOB object types yet.  Neither of those will help your transaction log issue though.

Comment: memory tables are still logged, but you can delay durability

Comment: I would appreciate a comment on the -1 so we can all learn from down votes.  The reply was factually correct and addressed the question directly.

Comment: Was not me, but a common theory is that answering off-topic questions encourages users to keep asking off-topic questions.

Comment: That doesn't mean delete it, though. Who cares about a down-vote? You're never going to explain every single down-vote. Some people are just arrow-happy.

Comment: 2014 also has [delayed durability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449490(v=sql.120).aspx) which compromises on the `D` aspect somewhat.